# javascript requestAnimationFrame in class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, requestanimationframe

Here's the code:

```
function myclass(arguments_nevermind)
{

var requestAnimationFrame= window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

this.running=false;

this.start = function()
{
    this.running= true;
    this.requestAnimationFrame( this.loop() );
}

this.loop = function()
{//some operations...
    if( this.running)
    {
        this.requestAnimationFrame( this.loop() );
    }
}

this.stop=function(){this.running=false;}

}
```

I just keep getting 'too much recursion'. I've tried a lot of possibilities on this one. Any idea how could I make this work? (I've already did it using the setInterval())

Comment: You are calling `this.loop` loop immediately (`this.loop()`) and pass the return value to `this.requestAnimationFrame`. You have to pass a function instead. `func()` **always** calls the function, there is no magic involved.

Comment: I tried it too. I get error:   TypeError: 'requestAnimationFrame' called on an object that does not implement interface Window.

Comment: That's a different problem then. If you want to store the function in a variable or property, you should bind it to `window`, e.g. `this.requestAnimationFrame = this.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window)`